# Denormalizing models in tastypie

Tags: django, api, tastypie, denormalization

What i'm trying to do is to add a query result from a model to a modelresource, as you can see in this block of code:

```
def dehydrate(self, bundle):
    bundle.data['image'] = place_image.image.get(place=1).get(cardinality=0)
```

I want to add a field to PlaceResource that will contain the image from place_site model where place=1 and cardinality=0. But im recieving an error:

```
The 'image' attribute can only be accessed from place_image instances
```

So, my question is: Is it impossible to use the query result from another model in a tastypie modelresource? Im sorry for my bad english, please correct me if something's wrong. Thanks for your time.
There's the complete code:

**MODELS.py:**

```
class place(models.Model):
    idPlace = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=70)


class place_image(models.Model):
    idImage = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    place = models.ForeignKey(place,
                              to_field='idPlace')
    image = ThumbnailerImageField(upload_to="place_images/", blank=True)
    cardinality = models.IntegerField()
```

**API.py**

```
from models import place
from models import place_image


class PlaceResource(ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        queryset = place.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'place'
        filtering = {"name": ALL}
        allowed_methods = ['get']


    def dehydrate(self, bundle):
        bundle.data['image'] = place_image.image.get(place=1).get(cardinality=0)

        return bundle


class PlaceImageResource(ModelResource):
    place = fields.ForeignKey(PlaceResource, 'place')

    class Meta:
        queryset = place_image.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'placeimage'
        filtering = {"place": ALL_WITH_RELATIONS}
        allowed_methods = ['get']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are getting is caused by the fact that you are accessing the `image` attribute of a model *class*, not *instance*.

The object that is being dehydrated in the `dehydrate` method is stored in `obj` attribute of the `bundle` parameter. Also, you are trying to filter `place_image` models to only those with `place=1` and `cardinality=0` by accessing the `image` attribute of `place_image` model class. Such filtering won't work as `image` is not a `ModelManager` instance. You should use `objects` attribute instead. Furthermore, `get()` method returns an actual model instance thus a subsequent call to `get()` will raise `AtributeError` as your `place_image` model instances have no attribute `get`.

So, all in all, your `dehydrate` should look like this:

```
def dehydrate(self, bundle):
    bundle.data['image'] = place_image.objects.get(place_id=1, cardinality=0).image
    return bundle
```

Notice that this code **requires** the `place_image` with desired values to exist, otherwise a `place_image.DoesNotExist` will be thrown.

There is also some redundancy in your models:

- `idPlace` and `idImage` can be removed, as django by default creates an `AutoField` that is a primary key called `id` when no other primary key fields are defined
- `place_image.place` field has a redundant `to_field` parameter, as by default `ForeignKey` points to a primary key field

Comment: Worked fine + good explanation, thanks!
About the redundancy, you are right, but i like to be explicit as python's zen says

Comment: Being explicit is one thing, and writing code that causes others to wonder why the author explicitly passed default arguments is other :P